# Display Push Notification in tableview in ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

1.I need to display all the incoming push notifications in list view   inside my iOS application. Is there a way to do so?

2.after 10 seconds , the push notifications should be dismissed or removed automatically. Is there a way to do so from the coding side or in server side are there any ways ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean push notifications sent to your app, or other apps?

Comment: ya it is possible , you can implement in two ways...

Comment: @Paulw11 push notifications sent to my app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you share the two ways?

Comment: @YogarajR -- sure , give 5 minutes

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik your 5 minutes not became completed??